# Hikaricp with Hibernate and MySql: one of either dataSource or dataSourceClassName must be specified

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I am working with:

- Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.3.8.FINAL
- HikariCP 2.3.2
- MySQL 5.6.22 Homebrew

**HikariCP** page has two interesting documentation/blog about MySQL and Hibernate

After to read the following tutorial about MySQL:

- [MySQL Configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration)

I have the following configuration about the DataSource:

**Alpha** (the best recommended and first try)

```
@Bean(name="dataSource", destroyMethod="close")
public DataSource dataSourceDevelopment() throws Exception{

    HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig();
    hc.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
    //hc.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //hc.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/manolodb_01");
    hc.setUsername("user");
    hc.setPassword("password");
    hc.setPoolName("hikaricp-manolodb_01-pool");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "manolodb_01");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");

    HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(hc);        
    return hds;
}
```

After to read the following tutorial about Hibernate:

- [Hibernate4](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4)

I have the following configuration:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource){

    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.manuel.jordan.domain");

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("database.hibernate.dialect", String.class));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class","com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class","org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql","true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments","true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth","30");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size","30");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size","30");//N + 1
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.SQL","true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.type","true");


    localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return localSessionFactoryBean;

}
```

**observe** I am using:
 `hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class","com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider");`

But I always receive:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: one of either dataSource or dataSourceClassName must be specified
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig.validate(AbstractHikariConfig.java:747)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:73)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider.configure(HikariConnectionProvider.java:80)
    ... 54 more
```

Even with **Beta**

```
@Bean(name="dataSource", destroyMethod="close")
public DataSource dataSourceDevelopment() throws Exception{

    HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig();
    //hc.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
    hc.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    hc.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/manolodb_01");
    hc.setUsername("user");
    hc.setPassword("password");
    hc.setPoolName("hikaricp-manolodb_01-pool");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "manolodb_01");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hc.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");

    HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(hc);        
    return hds;
}
```

I get the same error message:

I did realize if I comment

- `hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class","com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider");`

I have **no** errors. Why this behavior?

I think my configuration is correct because the second link says:

```
In order to use the HikariConnectionProvider in Hibernate 4.x add the    
following property to your hibernate.properties configuration file:

hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
```

And that is what I have…

I don't want include HikariCP configuration properties directly in the hibernate.properties how the second link offers too.

Comment: Your configuration is wrong. When injecting a datasource into hibernate you don't (nor should) specify a connection provider. That is only useful if you want hibernate to manage your datasource. So either put all the configuration in hibernate or no configuration at all.

Comment: I see, wondered why the second link does not mention that.

Comment: That is for plain hibernate configuration not for the Spring Hibernate HikariCP combo...

Comment: Ok, I understand, pls post your comment how a solution to mark it how resolved. But again, the 2nd tutorial gives the impression we have two options to configure: include or not include the `HikariCP configuration properties directly in Hibernate`.

Comment: You have 2 options, but those are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options to configure a `DataSource` for use with hibernate either you fully configure a `DataSource` in spring and inject it into the `dataSource` property of the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` or your use the hibernate properties to configure the `DataSource` in that case you must set the `hibernate.connection.provider_class`.